# What is the Fedora equivalent package name for 'freehep-graphics2d'?

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, scilab, freehep

I have been trying to install Scilab from Source. When i run

```
./configure
```

i get this error

```
configure: error: Could not find or use the Java package/jar freehep-graphics2d used by Freehep Graphics2D (looking for package org.freehep.graphics2d.VectorGraphics)
```

hence, i tried to install it in fedora 23 but could not find the package. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need EMF graphics support? If not, build with `./configure --without-emf` to remove this dependency.

Comment: As an aside, why not use scilab as already packaged in Fedora?

Comment: i tried doing that with dnf, but i figured that no C header files were included in usr/include. or anywhere else.

Comment: In fact, i can find no libraries in /usr/lib besides no headers in /usr/include, if i go for dnf.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: For include files, install `scilab-devel`. In general, you want `-devel` packages for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mattdm

Answer (score 0):

Old! last updated in 2007! Your best bet is to compile the source. Start with

```
$ svn checkout svn://svn.freehep.org/svn/freehep/tags/vectorgraphics-2.1.1/freehep-graphics2d freehep-graphics2d
```

There is a pom.xml, so use Maven to build it. Good luck!

Update: see the Centos instructions at https://wiki.scilab.org/Compiling%20Scilab%205.x%20under%20GNU-Linux%20Unix#Compilation_under_CentOS

What do you have at:

```
$SCILAB/thirdparty/freehep-util.jar
$jardir/freehep-graphicsio-emf.jar
```

Actually, the best bet is as suggested above in a comment, to disable this feature.